# Bluemix Blockchain service error with Fabric Composer

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Using fabric composer v0.7.0 I have deployed a business network to a Blockchain service on Bluemix (v0.6).

After the app runs for a while I get the following error:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error
at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:169:8)
```

This sometimes happens when executing the `composer network deploy` command as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This problem occurs because of the way the event hub works in
>   Hyperledger Fabric v0.6. The Node.js client for Fabric `hfc` maintains
>   a persistent connection to the event hub but does not cope well with
>   network blips/disconnects etc (it just kills the client). Persistent
>   connections aren't really cloud friendly as the network/routing will
>   just terminate idle connections after a while.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/7512977/simon-stone

### Ways to deal with this:

1. You could (probably should) have multiple instances of your application running so when one crashes another is still running to take over.
2. Calling `BusinessNetworkConnection.connect()` before every chaincode invoke to recreate the event hub connection. **Please note that this is not very efficient, as making the connection takes a while**

If the error occurs when deploying with the `composer-cli` you may want to try executing the command again after a minute or so.

Calling `BusinessNetworkConnection.ping()` during a set interval will not help with the issue because the problem is caused by the event hub, and events are only published on actual transactions. `ping()` is a read-only chaincode query that does not create a transaction.